# Apply different background image for different pages in react js

Tags: css, reactjs, background-image

I want to have a different background image for the login page and home page. If I apply the image to body tag then it gets applied to all the pages. And when I apply it to a specific login page, it works but it only gets applied according to the width and height of the login page.

Applied in body in index.css

```
body{
    background-image: url("http://web3canvas.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/littlevisuals-high-quality-hd-banner-images-stock-photos-free-laptop-topview-download.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is the login page

[image]

And this is the home page

[image]

And I want background image in only login page.

When I apply background image to only login page, this happens.
[image]

I have applied that image in the outermost div of the login page.

```
<div  className={classes.body}>
            <React.Fragment>
                <CssBaseline />
                <main className={classes.layout}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                            <LockIcon />
                        </Avatar>
                        <Typography variant="headline" className={classes.color}>Sign in</Typography>
                        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
                                <Field
                                    component={renderTextField}
                                    label="Email"
                                    id="email"
                                    name="email"
                                    value={email}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    fullWidth
                                />
                            </FormControl>
                            <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
                                <Field
                                    value={password}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    name="password"
                                    type="password"
                                    id="password"
                                    component={renderTextField}
                                    label="Password"
                                    className={classes.color}
                                    fullWidth />
                            </FormControl>
                            <Button type="submit"
                                disabled={pristine || submitting}
                                fullWidth
                                variant="outlined"
                                color="secondary"
                                className={classes.submit}
                            >
                                Submit
                                 </Button>
                        </form>
                        <Button
                            fullWidth
                            variant="outlined"
                            color="primary"
                            className={classes.submit}>
                            <Link to="/register">
                                New User ? Register Here
                                </Link>
                        </Button>
                        <SocialButton
                            fullWidth
                            variant="raised"
                            color="primary"
                            className="btn btn-danger form-control"
                            provider='google'
                            appId='967209745915-djav2bq5ic5r4ad9on3itp5a079s1ruu.apps.googleusercontent.com'
                            onLoginSuccess={this.handleSocialLogin}
                            onLoginFailure={this.handleSocialLoginFailure}
                            key={'google'}
                        >
                            Login with Google
                </SocialButton>
                    </Paper>
                </main>
            </React.Fragment>
            </div>
```

Help me out someone.

Edit --

I am using Material UI

This is the full login page code.

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { userActions } from '../../_actions';
import '../../index.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { history } from '../../_helpers/history';
import SocialButton from '../../SocialButton';
import compose from 'recompose/compose';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import LockIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
import { IndefiniteObservable } from '../../../node_modules/indefinite-observable';

const styles = theme => ({
    layout: {
        width: 'auto',
        display: 'block', // Fix IE11 issue.
        marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
        marginRight: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
        [theme.breakpoints.up(400 + theme.spacing.unit * 3 * 2)]: {
            width: 400,
            marginLeft: 'auto',
            marginRight: 'auto',
        },
    },
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 13,
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: `${theme.spacing.unit * 2}px ${theme.spacing.unit * 5}px ${theme.spacing.unit * 5}px`,
        background: 'linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(146, 135, 187, 0.8) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%)',
        transition: 'opacity 0.1s, transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.17, -0.65, 0.665, 1.25)',
        transform: 'scale(1)'
        // backgroundImage: `url("http://web3canvas.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/littlevisuals-high-quality-hd-banner-images-stock-photos-free-laptop-topview-download.jpg")`,
    },
    body: {
        backgroundImage: `url("http://web3canvas.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/littlevisuals-high-quality-hd-banner-images-stock-photos-free-laptop-topview-download.jpg")`,   
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
    },
    color: {
        color: 'black',
    },
    avatar: {
        margin: theme.spacing.unit,
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%', // Fix IE11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing.unit,
    },
    submit: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
        marginBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 2
    },
});

const renderTextField = ({
    input,
    label,
    meta: { touched, error },
    ...custom
}) => (
        <TextField
            hintText={label}
            floatingLabelText={label}
            errorText={touched && error}
            {...input}
            {...custom}
        />
    )

const validate = values => {
    const errors = {}
    const requiredFields = [
        'firstName',
        'lastName',
        'email',
        'favoriteColor',
        'notes'
    ]
    requiredFields.forEach(field => {
        if (!values[field]) {
            errors[field] = 'Required'
        }
    })
    if (
        values.email &&
        !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.email)
    ) {
        errors.email = 'Invalid email address'
    }
    return errors
}

class LoginPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // reset login status
        this.props.dispatch(userActions.logout());

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            submitted: false
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleSocialLogin = this.handleSocialLogin.bind(this);
        this.handleSocialLoginFailure = this.handleSocialLoginFailure.bind(this);

    }

    handleSocialLogin(user) {
        console.log(user)
        debugger;
        if (user) {
            this.props.dispatch(userActions.googlelogin(user));
        }
    }

    handleSocialLoginFailure = (err) => {
        console.error(err)
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        this.setState({ [name]: value });
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        debugger;
        e.preventDefault();

        this.setState({ submitted: true });
        const { email, password } = this.state;
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        if (email && password) {
            dispatch(userActions.login(email, password));
        }

    }


    render() {
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const { email, password, submitted } = this.state;
        const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props
        return (
            <div  className={classes.body}>
            <React.Fragment>
                <CssBaseline />
                <main className={classes.layout}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                            <LockIcon />
                        </Avatar>
                        <Typography variant="headline" className={classes.color}>Sign in</Typography>
                        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
                                <Field
                                    component={renderTextField}
                                    label="Email"
                                    id="email"
                                    name="email"
                                    value={email}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    fullWidth
                                />
                            </FormControl>
                            <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
                                <Field
                                    value={password}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    name="password"
                                    type="password"
                                    id="password"
                                    component={renderTextField}
                                    label="Password"
                                    className={classes.color}
                                    fullWidth />
                            </FormControl>
                            <Button type="submit"
                                disabled={pristine || submitting}
                                fullWidth
                                variant="outlined"
                                color="secondary"
                                className={classes.submit}
                            >
                                Submit
                                 </Button>
                        </form>
                        <Button
                            fullWidth
                            variant="outlined"
                            color="primary"
                            className={classes.submit}>
                            <Link to="/register">
                                New User ? Register Here
                                </Link>
                        </Button>
                        <SocialButton
                            fullWidth
                            variant="raised"
                            color="primary"
                            className="btn btn-danger form-control"
                            provider='google'
                            appId='967209745915-djav2bq5ic5r4ad9on3itp5a079s1ruu.apps.googleusercontent.com'
                            onLoginSuccess={this.handleSocialLogin}
                            onLoginFailure={this.handleSocialLoginFailure}
                            key={'google'}
                        >
                            Login with Google
                </SocialButton>
                    </Paper>
                </main>
            </React.Fragment>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

LoginPage.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { loggingIn } = state.authentication;
    return {
        loggingIn
    };
}

export default compose(
    withStyles(styles),
    connect(mapStateToProps, null),
    reduxForm({
        form: 'MaterialUIForm',
        validate
    })
)(LoginPage);
```

I will put the code on stackblitz in a few minutes

Comment: can you put down your code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you using css modules?

Comment: Your body style is not wrong, I guess it should be .body instead of body

Comment: did you try using css  `background: url("http://web3canvas.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/littlevisuals-high-quality-hd-banner-images-stock-photos-free-laptop-topview-download.jpg")  no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;`

Comment: Hello Karan, have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Create unique `classNames` for each component, wrap other content inside the `classNames` div element.

> for Login component

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="login">
        //other code
      </div>
    )
}
```

> for Home component

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="home">
        //other code
      </div>
    )
}
```

In index.css apply the color for the `classNames`.

```
.login {
   background: url("http://web3canvas.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/littlevisuals-high-quality-hd-banner-images-stock-photos-free-laptop-topview-download.jpg") no-repeat; 
   background-size: cover;
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
 }

.home {
  background: url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/mountain.jpg") no-repeat; background-size: cover;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It works but I am getting the background image for login page as i said in the third image.

Comment: try this you will get images for only particular component

Comment: Yes, I tried it and you are right I am getting what you said. But the background image I am getting in login page is what I showed in the third image. I am not getting the full image.

Comment: so your problem is its not covering ?

Comment: change css like this `.login {
  background: url("http://web3canvas.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/littlevisuals-high-quality-hd-banner-images-stock-photos-free-laptop-topview-download.jpg") no-repeat;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}`

Comment: Yeah, finally it worked, just replaced min-height and min-width with background-size: cover and no-repeat was not required. Thanks

Comment: if your image is small then no-repeat is required, i edited my ans too

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use styled Components, which is fully compatible with Material UI,
you can just replace the `<div className={classes.body}>` with your custom `<StyledBody>`

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledBody = styled.div`
  background: url('http://web3canvas.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/littlevisuals-high-quality-hd-banner-images-stock-photos-free-laptop-topview-download.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`;

export default function Login(props) {
  return (
    <StyledBody>
      // your login component
    </StyledBody>
  );
}
```

If you haven't already, be sure to install styled-components first with `npm i styled-components`

Of course the same css code would work however you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('image url')";
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.